# Сертификат и провижен

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, apple

Добрый день.

Мне предоставили сертификат и провижен на программу, и я должен был сделать тестовую сборку.

Но xCode говорит, что мой аккаунт типа не состоит в ни в одной тиме.

Что нужно, чтоб сделать билд? Владелец сертификата должен мой AppleDev аккаунт добавить в тиму?

А для того, чтоб я еще и на девайс потестил, мне надо дать данные девайса.

Я все правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Экспорт пусть сделает]

Пусть экспортируют тебе учетную запись или сам залогируй xcode. А потом жмяк на "обновить" и он сам подтянет провижны.